# Validating forms in HTML, PHP, and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

If I am defining a function in JavaScript at the top of my page that validates if the string entered in a form is (A-Z,a-z, or 0-9). And then I call that function when they submit it saying :

```
onsubmit="return Validator(this);"
```

If the function name is :

```
function Validator(form)
```

Why isn't it actually validating the string submitted when we actually click on submit, and is there a better way of validating forms?

Comment: FYI, this doesn't have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: Check out this link
http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/formvalidator
Its a contribution to YUI, examples are here
http://murdog05.github.com/yui3-gallery/index.html#formvalidator_examples
I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: Please post some of the body of Validator. Otherwise how can we tell what the problem is:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't submitting a string to Validator, you are submitting an input element. So you would do `if(form.element.value != "") ...` or something... And yes there is a [better way](http://mootools.floor.ch/en/labs/formcheck/forum-registration/)

Comment: No, input elements don't have submit events. It has to be a form.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly because the Validator function is not written correctly… but since you haven't shown us what it looks like, we can't say specifically why.

Perhaps it is expecting a String and you are giving it an HTMLFormElement.

Answer (score 1):

An onsubmit handler function needs to return false to cancel the event (form submission) if you want to not submit and show a validation error message instead.

***Plain Javascript approaches***:
[Form is still submitted even though listener function returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967483/form-is-still-submitted-even-though-listener-function-returns-false)

***jQuery approaches***:
[How to not submit a form if validation is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665470/how-to-not-submit-a-form-if-validation-is-false)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options for form validation.  Depending on your framework, you may want to use Jquery's validation.  If you go with yui, I have submitted a form validator that will be useful

[Here](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/formvalidator) is the gallery submission, from thee you can look at examples